# What I scrape from python is not the same as what I see from firebug

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am practicing to write a web crawler to crawl some interesting information from a website. I try this block of code on my personal website. It works as what I expect, but when I try to implement this code on a real website, it does not show what it should show. Does anyone have any ideas? The following is my code and results.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://angel.co/parkwhiz/jobs/284942-product-manager'
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
print soup.prettify()
```

Result from print

[image]

Result from firebug(or chrome inspect)

[image]

The title shows in the print is "Page not found - 404 - AngelList", but the title shows in firebug is "Product Manager Job at Parkwhiz - AngelList". Is there anything wrong with my code? Shouldn't these two be match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website is blocking the script as you're passing default `User-Agent` which tells the website that it is an automated Python script.

If you check the status code, you'll see that you're getting 404.

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://angel.co/parkwhiz/jobs/284942-product-manager')
>>> r.status_code
404
```

To overcome this, change the `User-Agent` to look like a real browser:

```
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
>>> r = requests.get('https://angel.co/parkwhiz/jobs/284942-product-manager', headers=headers)
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It really helps. One more question, I read documentation of request, but most of things that does not quite make sense to me. To better understand the package and use it properly, do you have any recommended source or what knowledge do I need to read the documentation? Thanks again. I am appreciated.

Comment: You can try reading this: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python